Why can not find the source vue component file in browser developer tool if vue component is written in typescript?
I am using vue2, my build tool is webpack@5.66.0. In order to debug the vue source component file easily, I add a configuration in output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate, the code is as below:
const resPath = path.normalize(info.resourcePath)
const isVue = resPath.match(/\.vue$/)
const isGenerated = info.allLoaders
const isTypeScript = info.allLoaders && info.allLoaders.includes('ts-loader')

const generated = `webpack-generated:///${resPath}?${info.hash}`
const vuesource = `vue-source:///${resPath}`

if (isVue) {
    if (!isGenerated || isTypeScript) {
        return vuesource
    } else {
        return generated
    }
} else {
    return vuesource
}

The devtool config is devtool: 'source-map'.
Now what's weird is, if the vue component is written in pure javascript, then I can find the source file easily, refer to below:

When click the above highlight part, show the content as below:

However, if the vue component is wrtten in typescript, which means has below declaration in vue component:
<script lang="ts">
  export default {
    ...
  }
</script>

When click the highlight part, it will show below content:

The full content is as below:
import mod from "-!../../../node_modules/happypack/loader.js?id=happyTs!../../../node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-4.use[1]!../../../node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./ManageApprovalAction.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts"; export default mod; export * from "-!../../../node_modules/happypack/loader.js?id=happyTs!../../../node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-4.use[1]!../../../node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js!../../../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./ManageApprovalAction.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts"

Does anybody know why can not show the original source file content in this case ?

How are you?
Plz ensure that your Webpack configuration accurately reflects the loader settings for both JavaScript and TypeScript files.
You may need to configure vue-loader and ts-loader properly to handle .vue files containing TypeScript.
you can ensure that the mappings are correct and that they point back to the correct *.vue files by using the browser's developer tools to inspect the generated source maps ,
By ensuring that your loaders are configured correctly, simplifying your logic, and possibly using additional source map loaders, you should be able to improve your debugging experience for Vue components, whether they are written in JavaScript or TypeScript. Make sure to test each change to observe how it affects your source maps in practice.
Happy coding!
